# Facebooks Apps: Some questions about them

Tags: facebook, fbml

**I am looking to develop a facebook app where the program draws a calander** *(or maybe the facebook API has a calendar widget?)* & you simply click a specific day & a little popup will occur.

I have looked at Facebooks developer site, FAQ & howtos, but there are still some questions I have:

- What "platform/API"(FBML/IFrame/etc) would you use to develop this in? I wish to have my app viewable in a web browser (even a browser on a Smart Phone), so that leads me to believe I should develop my app in FBML & not IFrame, connect or use Facebooks API in Android or iOS.
- Is a FBML app viewable in all Smart Phone web browsers?
- With FBML, do I have to have my own server? Is there a free server/host I can use that you know of?
- So far the only tutorials I can find for creating a FBML app are in PHP, do you know of a Java or Python tutorial?
- I have a feeling that because FBML refers to a canvas that the apps use HTML5(or is this FB's API canvas?), does that mean my app cannot be viewed by people who have browsers that cant run/use HTML5?
- Is a FBML app more like a Java Applet or would it be more like a Javascript HTML app. Ie, with the first we are running code on the java virtual machine, the latter we are directly interacting with HTML elements with javascript code over the top.

Thanks in advance for any insights

Answer (score 0):

[FBML](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/) is going away - read their official documentation on deprecating FBML.  You can even create tabs with iframe-hosted content now.  So this pretty much renders the rest of your FBML-based questions moot.  :)

So you're free to develop with whatever server-side code you want (e.g. PHP, ASP.NET, JSP, etc).  It makes no difference to the end-user, because the markup will (for the most part) render the same.

You may also find the [Facebook Developer Roadmap](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) a useful resource, which you can use to keep on top of what's coming and going and what SDKs you should leverage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So can I develop an IFrame app using Java? For my application/widget described above would you suggest just using connect or using IFrame?

Comment: I think you need to get your terminology and technologies straight.  Java or not doesn't matter - you're still going to render HTML with it.  You're definitely going to use iframes.  FB Connect is a separate thing - and from the sound of it, you'll want to use that too.